trace and determinant strictly positive but not strongly convex
Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function.
Denote by $H$ its hessian matrix and by $a$, $b$ its real eigenvalues.
Suppose there exists $c>0$ such that $a(x,y)b(x,y)>c$ and $a(x,y)+b(x,y)>c$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
I want to find an example of function $f$ satisfying the above hypotheses and such that $f$ is not strongly convex.

Necessarily, either $a(x,y)>c$ or $b(x,y)>c$. So I would like to find $f$ such that $a$ tends to infinity whereas in the same time $b$ tends to $0$.
For instance $a(x,y)=p(x,y)\exp(x^2)$, $b(x,y)=q(x,y)\exp(-x^2)$ for some polynomials $p$, $q$. But it is easy to show that there is no associated function $f$ whose hessian has eigenvalues $a$ and $b$.
Considering flat functions doesn't seem to lead anywhere.
Maybe looking for expressions depending on $sin(1/x)$.
It seems the result is false for in $1d$ so there should be an intricate relation between $x$ and $y$.

The result is true for functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, as then eigenvalue, determinant and trace of $f''$ coincide.

“Necessarily, either $a(x,y) > c$ or $b(x,y) > c$”: this is incorrect, if for instance $a=b=\frac{3}{2}$ and $c=2$. But the conclusion holds if you replace $c$ with $c/2$, so it’s immaterial.

If I did not misunderstand something then you are right and there is the following easy counterexample.
Suppose that the function $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. Then $f$ is strongly convex with parameter $m>0$ if and only if the minimum eigenvalue of $H$ is at least $m$ for all $(x,y)\in D$, see Wikipedia.
By Vieta's formulae, $a+b=f_{xx}+f_{yy}$ and $ab=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2$. Since $a(x,y)+b(x,y)>c$ and $a(x,y)b(x,y)>c$ we have $a(x,y)>0$ and $b(x,y)>0$, it is easy to check that $f$ is strongly convex iff
$$0<\inf_{(x,y)\in D} \frac{a(x,y)b(x,y)}{a(x,y)+b(x,y)}=\inf_{(x,y)\in D}\frac{f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y)-f_{xy}(x,y)^2}{f_{xx}(x,y)+f_{yy}(x,y)} .$$
Let $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x,y>0\}$. For each $x,y\in D$ put $f(x,y)=6x^2+6xy^2+y^4+6y^2$.
Then $f_x(x,y)=12x+6y^2$, $f_y(x,y)=12xy+4y^3+12y$, $f_{xx}(x,y)=12$, $f_{xy}(x,y)=12y$, and $f_{yy}(x,y)=12x+12y^2+12$. Then
$$a(x,y)+b(x,y)=f_{xx}(x,y)+f_{yy}(x,y)=24+12x+12y^2\ge 24,$$
$$a(x,y)b(x,y)=f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y)-f_{xy}(x,y)^2=144x+144\ge 24,$$
but
$$\inf_{(x,y)\in D} \frac{a(x,y)b(x,y)}{a(x,y)+b(x,y)}=\inf_{(x,y)\in D} \frac{144x+144}{24+12x+12y^2}=0.$$
